# Showing one function is greater than another function (or proving an inequality)

Tags: analysis, derivatives, inequality

How would you show that 
$e^x \lt \frac{1}{1-x} $ for $ 0 \lt x \lt 1 $?

I thought we could define a new function, $h=f-g$, where $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.
Then, move on to calculate the derivative of h and then show that it is negative, implying that h is decreasing. But I did not know how to show that h is negative in $(0,1)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove Exponential Function Inequality: $e^x \le \frac{1}{1-x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709681/prove-exponential-function-inequality-ex-le-frac11-x)

Comment: Oh cheers! Thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired inequality is, of course, equivalent to $$f(x):=e^x(1-x)<1$$ for $0<x<1$. We consider that
$$f'(x)=-xe^x\leq0$$
on $[0,1]$, with $f'(x)=0$ exactly when $x=0$. It follows, therefore, that $f$ is monotonically decreasing on $[0,1]$, with a local maximum at $x=0$ where $f(0)=1$.